# C++ 2d Vector subscript out of range error

Tags: c++, arrays, object, vector

Currently in my function, I have a method that declares a 2d vector.

```
vector <vector<test> > path(int x, int y) //Path function
{
vector <vector<test>> mazeArray(column, vector<test>(row)); //Declaring an object
    for (int a = 0; a < column; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < row; b++)
        {
            mazeArray[b][a].setX(b);
            mazeArray[b][a].setY(a);
        }
    }
}
```

For example, when i tried to run the function, path(10,10).

The double for loop works perfectly without any error, but however If i change the path for example, path(11,10) or path (11,13) or numbers that are not the same for both (int x and y), the error **vector subscript out of range** will be present.

Why is this so? Can anyone help me on this? Is there any way to fix it such that any value i type will be acceptable? Thanks.

Comment: Are your columns and rows switched?

Comment: Hi, I've tried switching them around but it still gives me the same error. I am not sure why, but the number must be consistent in order to not have the vector subscript out of range problem. Is there any way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop in the function

```
vector <vector<test> > path(int x, int y) //Path function
{
vector <vector<test>> mazeArray(column, vector<test>(row)); //Declaring an object
    for (int a = 0; a < column; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < row; b++)
        {
            mazeArray[b][a].setX(b);
            mazeArray[b][a].setY(a);
        }
    }
}
```

is wrong. You have to exchange b and a in indices. There should be

```
    for (int a = 0; a < column; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < row; b++)
        {
            mazeArray[a][b].setX(b);
            mazeArray[a][b].setY(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Take into account that the meaning of the function parameters is unclear because they are not used.:)

Answer (score 3):

```
mazeArray[b][a].setX(b);
```

In this statement, b can vary from [0,row-1], whereas mazeArray is having dimensions `column`*`row`. So the first index can have only have values from [0,column-1]. So most probably, you need to initialize the vector like this -:

`vector <vector<test>> mazeArray(row, vector<test>(column)); //Declaring an object`